# Sharing information between multiple C# projects in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a collection of VS2010 projects which are used in various solutions, but typically only a subset of these projects are used in any one solution. One of those projects (which I will refer to as the "base" project) exists in every solution and contains base implementations for the subclasses defined in the other projects. In other words, the base project is included in every solution because the other projects depend on it, but any of the dependent projects may or may not be included in any particular solution.

I want to know if there is a way for the base project to know which of the dependent projects exists in any one solution so that it can act accordingly. I thought that #defines would easily solve this problem (by #defining a unique symbol for each dependent project and including code into the base project accordingly), but #defined symbols can't be seen across projects. Is there an easy way to include different code in the base project depending on which dependent projects are in the solution?

EDIT: The language used in all of these projects is C#, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I can't really tell what your goal is here. The other solutions are what depend on the base, and it appears you're trying to make the base conditionally dependent on other solutions, but for what purpose? There's likely a better way, whatever your real goal is.  Examples or code would help.

Comment: It's a somewhat complicated situation, but I'll try to describe it. The base classes contain a byte array with information about what subclass it should become. I have some functions which parse this information and determine the type of the subclass, but these functions must be different in each separate application since not all of the dependent projects with the subclass definitions exist in each solution. If the base project could know which of the dependent solutions are present, the parsing functions could be moved to the base project by only including code for the existing projects.

Comment: @Steve maybe all of the subclass definitions should be part of the base project, or a new dependency for the base project?

Comment: Technically this is possible, but the reason that they are split into multiple projects is that there are around a thousand (and growing) subclasses, and it has been cleaner to only include the 100 or so subclasses used in each particular application.

Comment: Over a thousand subclasses?... I'll spare you the image I had in mind, but it had something to do with googling "You're doing it wrong."

Comment: *"The base classes contain a byte array with information about what subclass it should become"*  Ignoring the other possible issues around your design, it sounds like your base class is constructing it's derived classes, which sounds wrong.  If you had some kind of builder/factory patterns then each project might be able to register a builder with the *base builder*.  You may also want to consider whether or not you could benefit from one of the many dependency injection frameworks to help control your construction.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do it extract the common projects in a separate solution, and use them as references in the other solutions.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question: "I want to know if there is a way for the base project to know which of the dependent projects exists in any one solution **so that it can act accordingly**"

Comment: Well I understood that he needs to include the base project in different solution, why not extract it? and build it separately, may be I misunderstood the problem